# Sentry: Transactions quota 80% depleted

Tags: sentry

I get this mail from sentry:

## Sentry: Transactions quota 80% depleted

> Approaching Transactions Quota
>
> Your organization FooBar has consumed 80% of its transactions capacity for the current usage period. It’s important to keep in mind that, should you hit your quota, and consume your on-demand spend, any excess transactions will be dropped until you roll over into the next period after Dec. 18, 2021.

I just want to use use sentry to monitor uncaught exceptions.

But it seems that sentry monitors all my transactions. That's not what I want.

How can I disable the monitoring of my transactions, so that only uncaught exceptions get monitored?

Answer (score 5):

If you reduce the `traces_sample_rate`, then less samples will be sent to sentry.

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://39f146...@xxx.ingest.sentry.io/xxx",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    traces_sample_rate=0.1,  # < ------------------- reduce this
```

Docs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/bottle/configuration/sampling/

Comment: Moreover, the quotas are independent. Even if you reach the transaction limit errors will still be processed as long as you don't reach the error limit. Checkout: https://forum.sentry.io/t/with-transaction-capacity-reached-will-errors-still-be-reported/12983

Comment: I wasn't sure the term of transaction. transaction is used for performance monitoring in sentry: https://docs.sentry.io/product/performance/